# A problem when try to zoom in & out of UIButton with CAAnimationGroup

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, caanimation

no have animation , cause i do it incorrect ?

```
-(void)swipeanimateDidStop {

    for (UIView *subview in self.swipingCell.backView.subviews){
        NSLog(@"%@",subview);
        // subview is UIButton
        [subview.layer addAnimation:[self ZoomAnimation] forKey:@"Zoom"];

    }
}

-(CAAnimationGroup *)ZoomAnimation {
    CAAnimationGroup *ZoomAnimation = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    CABasicAnimation *In = [self zoomIn];

    ZoomAnimation.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: In, nil];
    ZoomAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
    return ZoomAnimation;
}

-(CABasicAnimation *)zoomIn {
    CABasicAnimation *ZoomInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    ZoomInAnimation.beginTime = 0.0f;
    ZoomInAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0];
    ZoomInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    ZoomInAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
    return ZoomInAnimation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `zoomIn` method. The key path should be `transform.scale` (since it is zoom).

```
CABasicAnimation *ZoomInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
```